# Create comment with services 3.X on Android with JSON

Tags: services

I'm developing one Android app.

I'm trying to post a comment from the app to Drupal via Services module, but I can't send a JSON data to the module, there is the Java code:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://example.com/serviceapi/comment");

String datos = "{\"name\":\""+username+"\",\"uid\":"+uid+",\"nid\":"+nid+",\"comment_body\":{\"und\":[{\"value\":\""+comment+"\",\"format\": \"filtered_html\"}]}}";

//add raw json to be sent along with the HTTP POST request
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(datos);
se.setContentType("application/json");
httppost.setEntity(se);

httppost.setHeader("X-CSRF-Token", token);

BasicHttpContext mHttpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
CookieStore mCookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();

//create the session cookie
BasicClientCookie cookie = new BasicClientCookie(session_name, session_id);
cookie.setVersion(0);
cookie.setDomain("example.com");
cookie.setPath("/");
mCookieStore.addCookie(cookie);
cookie = new BasicClientCookie("has_js", "1");
mCookieStore.addCookie(cookie);
mHttpContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, mCookieStore);

//Send the request
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost,mHttpContext);

//Get the drupal response data
Log.e("Estatus code", Integer.toString(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()));

BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
String line = "";
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
  result.append(line);
}

Log.e("Data",result.toString());
```

But I get the following error:

E/Estatus code﹕ 500

E/Data﹕ ["A nid must be provided"]

I don't know what can I do, if I provide a nid, why services don't get the nid, I try in Firefox plugin [Poster](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/poster/), and that JSON code works, with Poster I can add comments.